# Can typescript assign index-based generic types from a union in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a React component that applies generic typings to props. Below is a simplified example:

```
interface Props<T> {
  data: T
}
const MyComponent = <T,>({ data }: Props<T>) => <div /> // output not important
```

Let's say I want to create a component, `MyGenericList` that iterates over an array of values (each index-based value could be different type) and renders `MyComponent`.

How can I type `MyGenericList` such that each iteration of `MyComponent` is typed based on the type of the index-based value? Here's what I've done so far, which doesn't work:

```
interface Props<T> {
  data: (keyof T[])[];
}
const MyGenericList = <T,>({data}: Props<T>) => {
  return (
    <>{data.map(d => <MyComponent<how to get index-based generic typing of 'd' here?> data={d} /></>
  );
}
```

The ideal consumption of `MyGenericList` would be like so:

```
<MyGenericList<string | number | string[]>  data={['someString', 45, ['string', 'string2']} />
```

Comment: Looks like runtime information to me, typescript won't be able to infer the type of each element individually.

Comment: @known-as-bmf the generic component ```MyGenericList``` couldn't infer, but it wouldn't need to since wherever it's consumed will know during compile time what the possible types are.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by doing:

```
interface Props<T> { data: T[][] };
const MyGenericList = <T,>({ data }: Props<T>) => (
  <>{data.map(d => <MyComponent<typeof d[0]> /> )}</>
)
```